# chrome deletes my extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chromium

I am developing an extension that uses chrome's Native messaging. After setting the key value in my extension (for native messaging) chrome goes bananas and deletes my files after closing chrome. Turning off sync extensions somehow keeps my files in tact, but it still removes the extension from itself every reboot. I can't figure out if this is some bizarre bug I've stumbled upon or this has to do with not being able to install non web-store extensions

Comment: Happens to me too. I usually see the little dialog that gives a warning about non web store extensions. But it replaces my unpacked extension with the one with the same ID from the webstore.

Comment: How do you load the extension?

Comment: unpacked in dev mode

Answer (score 1):

**Problem**

As you can read on [google forums (productforums.google.com)](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/chrome/d35tIyH8dVM/UGj_iga3x8UJ), posted on 04.09.2015, new versions of Google Chrome will automatically disable extension that are have not been installed from Chrome Web Store. There is no option to change this behaviour.

> Some extensions come bundled with others, which causes Chrome to ask
>   whether you want to install them (or not). However, bad actors have
>   abused this mechanism, bypassing the prompt to silently install
>   malicious extensions that can override browser settings and alter the
>   user experience in undesired ways.

...

> Since these malicious extensions are not hosted on the Chrome Web
>   Store, it’s difficult to limit the damage they can cause. This is why
>   we announced in November that as part of our continuing security
>   efforts, all extensions for Windows users must be hosted in the
>   Chrome Web Store.

**Solutions**

**1.** Use a different browser. For example, Opera (version > 15) and SRWare Iron browsers extensions are 100% compatible and they don't get disabled on each browser startup. All the tools from Google Chrome are available in these browsers.

**2.** Pack the extension (idea taken from [this url](https://superuser.com/a/768154/124884)). Open the extension page, activate "Developer Mode"; Click "Load unpacked extension..."; Search trough your directory tree for the directory where you unpacked your extension and click OK; Disadvantages: Chrome nags you to disable the extension at each start up

Comment: I saw that link before, but the extension is one that is already unpacked  It's one That I'm making myself. The example extension from chrome on native messaging does not uninstall itself, but mine does, but only after adding the key attribute. I'm also using chromium not chrome already if that matters

Answer (score 1):

If you are copy/pasting an installed extension that no longer exists, you can modify the manifest and remove:

- the key
- the update_url

Then load it again and it will work and assume you are developing it.